# Yeoman iOS ObjectiveC Generator

Tags: ios, objective-c, yeoman

I am trying to achieve scaffolding using the Yeoman tool. Right now i am able to create the project using the tool but the template options does not modify the **pbxproj** file. Due to this the name of the project remains the same for the template instead of modifying the properties.

Has some tried some kind of a stuff like this earlier ? If yes i would really 
appreciate if someone can give me some lead about this.

Comment: Have you tried using [liftoff](https://github.com/thoughtbot/liftoff)?

Comment: thanks but there is something i am trying to achieve and the constraint is I have to use the Yeoman as the tool. But thats alright I am able to figure out the stuff. Was a small mistake that i was actually doing while performing the copyTpl function.